# Find the first element that occurs only once

Tags: algorithm

This was a Google interview puzzle.

The problem is to find the first element in an array that occurs only once.

For example, `abaaacdgadgf` is given. We need to output `b`.

The simple solution seems to be to first count every element using a hashtable, and then loop through again to get the first element. It will use 2 loops.

Is it possible to get the result only use 1 loop?

I tried to figure it out, but it seems impossible.

Comment: The key word is "first"

Comment: @JanDvorak: the accepted answer to the linked question is very poor so that question is in essence unanswered.

Comment: @n.m. how come? the source code is pretty readable IMO

Comment: @n.m. the top-voted answer even has an explanation

Comment: @JanDvorak: the code in the accepted answer is just a naïve quadratic algorithm, and a poorly implemented one at that. It would not get you very far in a Google interview.

Comment: @n.m. ah, right. However, if you replace an ordinary list with a linked hash...

Comment: @n.m. Isn't the correct action then to put a bounty on that question instead of asking another? But since OP doesn't have that much reputation, I'm not really sure.

Comment: Aah... Found a solution. Posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17549192/1903116. **The key idea here, is to process the data backwards.**

Answer (score 4):

The hash table points to items in a linked list. When adding an item the hashtable entry is created and the pointer added to the tail of the list. When a duplicate is found then the item can be removed from the list.

The first element to occur only once will be the first item in the list.

This code is a little untidy because most of the code is linked list implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct stLISTITEM
{
    char data;
    struct stLISTITEM* previous;
    struct stLISTITEM* next;
} LISTITEM;

char firstCharThatOccursOnce(const char* s) {
    char ret;
    LISTITEM* head;
    LISTITEM* tail;
    LISTITEM* table[CHAR_MAX + 1] = {NULL}; /* Just pretend this is a hash table please */
    LISTITEM* cur;
    int i;

    head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    tail = malloc(sizeof(*tail));

    head->next = tail;
    tail->previous = head;
    tail->data = '\0'; /* If all characters are repeated then return NULL character */

    for (; *s; s++) {
        cur = table[*s];

        if (cur == NULL) {
            /* Item hasn't been seen before */

            cur = malloc(sizeof(*cur));
            cur->data = *s;

            /* Add it to the end of the list */
            tail->previous->next = cur;
            cur->previous = tail->previous;
            tail->previous = cur;
            cur->next = tail;

            /* Add it to the table */
            table[*s] = cur;
        }
        else if (cur->next == NULL) {
            /* Seen it before, but already removed */
        }
        else {
            /* Seen it before, remove from list */
            cur->previous->next = cur->next;
            cur->next->previous = cur->previous;

            cur->next = NULL;
            cur->previous = NULL;
        }
    }

    ret = head->next->data;

    for (i = 0; i <= CHAR_MAX; i++) {
        free(table[i]);
    }

    free(head);
    free(tail);

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char result = firstCharThatOccursOnce("abaaacdgadgf");

    printf("'%c' (%i)\n", result, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I find the "first element to occur" in Hash Table?

Comment: You don't, you find it at the head of the linked list.

Comment: @Matt what is the time complexity and space complexity of your approach?

Comment: @Matt Figured it out: Time complexity: O(N*D) where D is the number of distinct characters in input string.And Space Complexity: O(D)
Am I right?

Comment: time complexity is O(N),i guess.Why it need to use double linklist?signle linklist can't fit?

Comment: @liumilan: How? Are you doing constant amount of work for each element?

Comment: @Aravind, Why would you multiply it though? You don't iterate through N items every time you find a distinct one.

Comment: @liumilan, It's doubly linked because I read from the back and from the front. Doubly linked lists allow you to delete an item in the middle without iterating over the list, singly linked won't let you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution:

Each 'char' has 4 stats possible:

- 1 : never seen.
- 2 : seen one
- 3 : eliminated because of multi occurence.
- 4 : qualified

I create an array of size 26(for each 'char') for storing stats of chars
Qualified elements are put at the end of dual linked list.

Scan the input data and do all the update as necessary.
Then scan the list from begin to end. The first non 'eliminated (state 3)'
is your answser.

```
complexity : n+(26x3) where n = length(dataset)
```

Comment: Nothing in the question (except the example) indicates that there's only 26 possible values.

Comment: What about chinese texts? Or arabic? Or german?

Comment: You are right, I said 26 because of the problem presentation and the C tag (I think we don't speak about unicode, but C chars). For an arbitrary hight number of char, you can replace this array with an hashmap. Non existing element in the map will be supposed to be in state 'never seen'. With this technics complexity will always be ( number of different char x n ).

Comment: The question asks if it is possible with only 1 loop though.

Comment: The solution do only one loop over input data.

Comment: @MrK, it doesn't say input data, it says "Is it possible to get the result only use 1 loop?"

Comment: Sorry I translate the "one loop" into 'n'  complexity question. A one loop question is so strange. Many sub parts of programs have loop inside, malloc, freeing, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the hashtable, instead of maintaining counts, maintain the first index where the element was encountered. Also maintain a sorted set of all unique-so-far elements, keyed on that index. Afterwards, just look for the minimal key remaining in the sorted set.

```
encountered = dict()
unique = sorted_set()

for i in range(len(A)):
    elem = A[i]
    if elem in encountered:
        first_index = encountered[elem]
        del unique[first_index]
    else:
        unique[i] = elem
        encountered[elem] = i

min_index = unique.keys()[0]
first_unique_elem = A[min_index]
```

Comment: `min` is implicitly a loop.

Comment: That's why a sorted set is preferable to a dict. But Python doesn't have a well-known one. Change `unique = dict()` to `unique = sorted_set()` and `min_index = min(unique.keys())` to `min_index = unique.keys()[0]` if you like.

Comment: @Ben Use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the other answers simply because I want to give it a go myself.
Let's iteratively improve our solution.
Our analysis in terms of time and space complexity will require us to state a few things clearly at first:

Let

```
N = length of string 
M = numbers of characters in alphabet
```

Brute force algorithm is to traverse the string and for each element of string we search to its right to see if it has a duplicate.
Time Complexity:O(N<sup>2</sup>)
Space Complexity:O(1)

Can we do better?
Sure, we can traverse the string and make count of many times a character appears.Make another traversal through the string to find the first character that has count 1.
Time Complexity:O(N+M)
Space Complexity:O(M)

Why is this O(N+M)?
Because we need to initialize the elements of the count array to 0 first.So even if input is "a", we need to initialize the count array for M elements.

Can we do better?
First let's state to the interviewer that this task is Omega(N), simply because we have to see each element of the string atleast once.Realize this by seeing a input instance of "aaaaaaz"
So we are not aiming to better our time complexity, simply making the actual running time better by doing **just one traversal through the string**.
This is indeed possible.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  if(visited[i]==-2)continue;
  if(visited[i]==-1)visited[i]=i;continue;
  visited[i]=-1;
}
int F=N;
char res=' ';
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
  if(visited[i]>=0)
  {
    F=min(F,visited[i]);
    res=A[visited[i]];
  }
}
return res;
```

Time Complexity:O(N+M)
Space Complexity: O(M)

Can we do better?

Can we do this in O(N) perhaps?
I'm still thinking of a way to do this in true O(N).IF I hit upon a solution, I will update this answer.

Comment: In fact ,your method is similar to the common method,count the number,and find out the first

Comment: I never claimed my method to be superior to any listed before.That is why I put the first line saying I haven't read the other answers before answering.Sorry if it's a repeat.Answering this helped me think over a few points.

Comment: @liumilan: I just noticed that you are the questioner, did you have a google interview? BTW, I have pointed an important fact that none of the analysis is truly O(N).People seem to overlook that often.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a hash table you may use a trie. If input data conspire against your hash function, a hashtable will get you quadratic performance. The trie is immune to that.

As for another loop, I would not worry about it too much. It's the same complexity asymptotically. Whatever you win by eliminating the loop, you are likely to lose in increased complexity of the rest of the code.